# Can we connect multiple database in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, multiple-databases

I am facing this issue to connect to another database.

Below is my code. I have defined two databases but when I try to fetch all the records I get below error:

`Table 'crm.cdr_Feb2015' doesn't exist.`

even though I have loaded the database in controller it take the default database as for selecting the details.

```
$active_group = 'default';
    $active_record = TRUE;

    $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
    $db['default']['username'] = 'root';
    $db['default']['password'] = '*****';
    $db['default']['database'] = 'crm';
    $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
    $db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
    $db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
    $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['cache_on'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
    $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['stricton'] = TRUE;

    $db['asterisk']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
    $db['asterisk']['username'] = 'root';
    $db['asterisk']['password'] = '*****';
    $db['asterisk']['database'] = 'asterisk';
    $db['asterisk']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
    $db['asterisk']['dbprefix'] = '';
    $db['asterisk']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
    $db['asterisk']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db['asterisk']['cache_on'] = TRUE;
    $db['asterisk']['cachedir'] = '';
    $db['asterisk']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db['asterisk']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db['asterisk']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db['asterisk']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db['asterisk']['stricton'] = TRUE;
```

Now in My Controller I have loaded the database :

```
  public function index()
{
    $this->load->database('asterisk', TRUE);

    $test =$this->cdr_m->get();
    var_dump($test);

}
```

The Model File :

```
    <?php
     class Cdr_M extends MY_Model
    {

    protected $_table_name = 'cdr_Feb2015';
    protected $_order_by = '';
    protected $_timestamps = TRUE;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 public function index()
{
    $this->db = $this->load->database('asterisk', TRUE);

    $test =$this->cdr_m->get();
    var_dump($test);

}
```

Comment: You can use $this->db2 = $this->load->database('db2', TRUE);$this->db2->get('table_name');

Comment: This is not working : **$this->db1 = $this->load->database('db2', TRUE);
              $this->db2 = $this->load->database();
              echo $this->db1->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS CT FROM LiveCalls")->row()->CT;
              echo '<br/>';
              echo $this->db2->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS Ag FROM Agents")->row()->Ag;**.When using two database in same method.How to use default db as well.

Comment: Here **LiveCalls** belong to db2 and **Agents** belong to default group

Comment: Bugfixer,  $this->db1 = $this->load->database('db1', TRUE); $this->db2 = $this->load->database('db2', TRUE);echo $this->db1->query("SELECT COUNT() AS CT FROM LiveCalls")->row()->CT; echo '<br/>'; echo $this->db2->query("SELECT COUNT() AS Ag FROM Agents")->row()->Ag;.

Comment: Or if you have default db set, simply `$this->db2 = $this->load->database('db2', TRUE);echo $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT() AS CT FROM LiveCalls")->row()->CT; echo '<br/>'; echo $this->db2->query("SELECT COUNT() AS Ag FROM Agents")->row()->Ag;`

Comment: Hey Could you Please Help me with this  :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266975/how-to-deduct-balance-from-reseller-dynamically-in-php-codeigniter

Answer (score 2):

`$this` is the instance of your default database. You need to assign in into different variable

```
$this->db2 = $this->load->database('asterisk', TRUE);
$test = $this->db2->cdr_m->get();
var_dump($test);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but got an error :Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_driver::$cdr_m

Answer (score 2):

Config/database.php

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'xxxxx';
$db['default']['database'] = 'CloudAgent';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

$db['db2']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['db2']['username'] = 'root';
$db['db2']['password'] = 'xxxxx';
$db['db2']['database'] = 'Asterisk';
$db['db2']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['db2']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['db2']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['db2']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['db2']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['db2']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['db2']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['db2']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['db2']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['db2']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['db2']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Controller :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Analytics extends CI_Controller {


    function __construct()
          {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();
            $this->db2 = $this->load->database('db2',TRUE); 

          }

}
```

Query  :

```
$in_calls = $this->db2->query('SELECT DATE_FORMAT(query_time,"%Y-%m-%d %h:%i%p") AS FromHour,total_calls AS callcount FROM LiveCalls WHERE DATE(query_time) = DATE(NOW())');
```

`LiveCalls` table belong to `Asterisk` database.

Comment: Could you please help me with this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266975/how-to-deduct-balance-from-reseller-dynamically-in-php-codeigniter